# Deleting a Excel file from QTP

Tags: qtp

I have a following  code in QTP:

```
Dim objexcel
Set objexcel = createobject("Excel.application")

objexcel.Visible = True

objexcel.Workbooks.Add
objexcel.Cells(1,1).Value =  "ABCDE"
objexcel.ActiveWorkBook.SaveAs("J:\Test.xls")
```

How do I close the file and delete it, I tried many ways but I am ending up getting object error.

Thanks in advence

Answer (score 1):

You need to create object of class `Filesystemobject` to delete any file, so code should be like this

```
Dim objExcel,objFSO
Set objExcel = createobject("Excel.application")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
objExcel.Visible = True
objExcel.Workbooks.Add
objExcel.Cells(1,1).Value =  "ABCDE"
objExcel.ActiveWorkBook.SaveAs("J:\Test.xls")
objExcel.Workbooks.Close
objExcel.Quit
set objExcel = nothing
objFSO.DeleteFile("J:\Test.xls")
Set objFSO =  nothing
```

Comment: Thanks, 
Now I got the issue, without the Filesystemobject it would be an issue.